# MLB Pitch Types "Back in the Day"

Tags: history, mlb, pitching

I was thinking how hard it would be to approach DiMaggio's 56 game hit streak these days.
Not only are there defensive shifts, specialized pitchers to get certain guys out, faster overall pitch speeds, etc...but what were pitch selections like?

Did pitchers have two-seamers, cutters, sinkers, etc back in the middle part of the 20th century?

Answer (score 1):

I think that a comprehensive source could be found in this book by [Neyer/James -
 The Guide to Pitchers: An Historical Compendium of Pitching, Pitchers, and Pitches](https://www.abebooks.com/NeyerJames-Guide-Pitchers-Historical-Compendium-Pitching/18213898341/bd).

Comment: While it may be a great source, Stack Exchange strongly prefers answers to be self-contained. Jonathan, could you please try and summarise the relevant parts of the book in your answer?

Comment: It seems the question may be a bit large in scope in for self-contained answers (there is a whole book about it, after all?), though I too would certainly find a self-contained answer of value.   Jonathan it sounds like you've read the book and could potentially give a better explanation, though it is understandable that it could be a real time labor to be thorough!  I appreciate the resource though, as it does put a direction in play for getting an answer to this question.